# Indexes on tables

Tags: indexing, db2, query-performance

I wrote a query in DB2 which uses inner join on four tables. I also created an index with four columns on fourth table in the same order the columns were being accessed in where clause of the query. But the index which I had created is not being used when I check the performance of the query using EXPLAIN. Anyone faced similar issue or know the reason for this?

Let A,B,C,D are my tables and d1,d2,d3,d4 are columns of table-D. In where clause the conditions are like `a1=d1,b1=d2,c1=d3,c2=d4`(a1,b1,c1 are columns in tables A,B,C). And my index on table-D is "CREATE INDEX index_name 
ON table_name (d1,d2,d3,d4);"

Comment: The order of `WHERE` conditions has no relation to the order of columns in an index.

Comment: Is your inner join doing any filtering? Can you post more EXPLAIN information or output?

Comment: Perhaps the optimiser decided the index didn't help in this particular query.

Comment: Its working after i created foreign keys for the columns used in where clause of table-D referring to corresponding tables A,B,C. Thanks a lot for your response mates :)